# Hardy-Littlewood circle method for non-diagonal quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

In short, the question is for any references describing how to use the Hardy-Littlewood circle method to find an asymptotic for the number of solutions to $F(x_1, ..., x_s) = k$ for $(x_1, ..., x_s) \in \mathbb{Z}^s$, where $F$ is some indefinite integral quadratic form, and $k\neq 0$ is a fixed integer.

An old paper of Sarnak et. al. (A Proof of Siegel's Weight Formula, see [here](https://collaborate.princeton.edu/en/publications/a-proof-of-siegels-weight-formula) or [here, for a PDF](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.543.8732&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) mentions that solving such a problem can be done with the Hardy-Littlewood circle method if $s\geq 5$ (the paper mentions this in section 2, just before formula 2.2). They mention the $s=4$ case is harder, and provide a reference to a paper; I tracked down the paper they refer to, although again it seems to only cover the diagonal case. I am not very intereseted in this case; I just want to see how to solve it for $s\geq 5$ for non-diagonal forms. I found some [lecture notes](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Egyujino/Sarnak%202020.pdf) of a course given by Sarnack covering the case of diagonal forms for $s\geq 5,$ but I do not see how to generalize. Is there some easy way to go from knowing this result for diagonal forms to non-diagonal ones, or some other source which covers solutions to indefinite forms? The proof given by Sarnack in those notes seems to use in a fundamental way the fact that the form is diagonal, so that a certain factorization can work.

Comment: Quadratic forms can always be diagonalized by a linear change of variables, so there is almost no loss of generality in restricting to the diagonal case (the situation is quite different in higher degree, already for cubic forms there is a huge difference in our understanding of the diagonal and the general case).

Comment: One cannot diagonalise over $\mathbb{Z}$ in general, and the OP is interested in integer solutions

Comment: That's true, but the diagonalization introduces at most a finite number of congruence conditions on our variables (in fact only parity conditions since we at most need to divide by 2), so that's something the Circle Method can deal with. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: My understanding is the simplest way to get the circle method to work using congruence conditions is to make the change of variables imposed by the congruence conditions then apply the circle method to the resulting equations. So in the OP's case this method doesn't help and just gives the original (non-diagonal) equations back again.

Comment: Hmm, I am still not sure I understand. So let's say our diagonal form will be $\sum_{i=1}^m a_ix_i^2+\sum_{j=1}^m a_jy_j^2$ where the $x_i$ are restricted to even variables and the $y_i$ restricted to odd variables. (This, I think we agree, we can always achieve by diagonalization.) Then our exponential sum factorizes nicely into a product where the factors are essentially of the form $\sum_{x} e(\alpha x^2)$ where $x$ is either restricted to even or odd integers in an interval. Isn't this sum almost exactly as easy to handle as the classical sum without the parity condition?

Comment: @Christian: why not try to write a detailed answer?

Comment: I added an anwer now. I just realized that my earlier claim about "at most dividing by 2" was nonsense, we might need to divide by something bigger, but that does not change anything, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "best" way to deal with quadratic forms using the circle method is via Heath-Brown's delta symbol method.

You can read about this in detail in the paper:
Heath-Brown - A New Form of the Circle Method, and its application to Quadratic Forms

Theorem 4 in particular gives an asymptotic formula for the problem you mention. Note that Heath-Brown is also able to obtain results for 4 variables.

Answer (score 2):

One reason to restrict to diagonal quadratic forms is that this is almost no loss of generality: Quadratic forms can always be diagonalized over $\mathbb{Q}$ by a linear change of variables.

There are several issues, but they can be resolved:

1. Since we are interested in integer solutions, as pointed out by Dan, we need to be careful with denominators. However, the diagonalization introduces at most finitely many congruence conditions on our new variables.
   This is not a big problem since your exponential sum will then factor as a product of terms like $\sum_{\vert x\vert \le P, x \equiv a (q)} e(\alpha x^2)$ and for the purposes of the circle method these can be treated just as the classical sum without the congruence condition.
2. If you want a precise asymptotic for the integer solutions inside some growing box (rather than just upper and lower bounds of the correct order of magnitude), you might need to be careful because your box gets distorted by the change of variables. However, this can be resolved by an easy enveloping argument.

So all of this is fine, as long as we fix our quadratic form. If we want to obtain results that are uniform over a family of quadratic forms, for instance with an explicit dependence on the size of the coefficients of our form, this approach can become problematic and is probably not the ideal one.

Comment: Maybe I'm overcomplicating things, but it seems like the congruence conditions introduced end up being rather difficult to work with. Is there some easy concrete way to see what congruence conditions arise? The most explicit description I can get is to impose every possible set of congruence conditions modulo the determinant of the change of variables on the first $s-1$ variables, and then solve the congruence to see which congruence conditions on the last variable $x_s$ give an integer vector, and then sum up over all possibilities. But this seems quite the mess to add up in the end.

Comment: I think of it as follows: Let $Q$ be the denominator to which we have congruences for our variables. Then just decompose your counting problem as a sum over counting problems with variables restricted to $x_1 \equiv a_1 (Q),\dots x_n \equiv a_n (Q)$ (where $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ runs through all tuples of residue classes modulo Q satisfying the congruence conditions. In other words, I don't care about the "complete description" of the congruence condition such as $x_i \equiv x_j \mod Q$ but just treat every possible combination of residues modulo Q separately.

Comment: In a concrete case, when Q is large, this would indeed become quite a mess, but you can argue abstractly that only the singular series depends on the congruence condition, and indeed only the p-factors for primes $p$ dividing $Q$. Then you can argue that these contributions exactly add up to the local density modulo primes dividing $Q$ that you would expect. In other words, you do get exactly the singular series you could have computed directly from the non-diagonal form, the change to a diagonal form is just made to make the analytic machinery in the proof work more nicely.